# Should library include headers have a directory prefix?

Tags: c++, c, directory, include, pkg-config

I'm gonna use [SDL2](https://wiki.libsdl.org/FrontPage) as an example here.

In C++ in general, when I consume SDL2 headers, should I have the directory "SDL2" in my include path, i.e.:

```
#include "SDL2/SDL.h"
```

or should I leave it out, i.e.:

```
#include "SDL.h"
```

I'm very confused of what the good convention is. If I install the sdl2 library and execute the following command line:

```
$ pkg-config --cflags --libs sdl2
```

I get:

```
-D_THREAD_SAFE -I/usr/local/include/SDL2 -L/usr/local/lib -lSDL2
```

which implies that I should leave out the directory:

```
#include "SDL.h"
```

However, looking at a sibling library of SDL, called SDL_image, I can see that inside `SDL_image.h` they have the directory included:

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL_version.h>
#include <SDL2/begin_code.h>
```

Who is doing it "wrong" here, pkg-config or SDL_image ?

Comment: if there's a "good convention" regarding this, I've never seen or heard of it. Probably comes down to how many include paths the developer(s) feel like typing/entering into the build system (most will vote for less). If you happen to have header files in different directories with same name (probably a bad idea), then you would have to specify the parent directory.

Comment: I work on a project that uses a mountain of generated code, (I get the libraries and header files), and the header files are spread out into 50+ directories. So I include that root header file directory in the build system and then do `#include <path/to/header.h>` whenever I want to use one. No way I'm typing every conceivable header path into Visual Studio project include paths just so I can `#include <header.h>`.

Comment: I think this is pretty "opinion based" but I would say yes. It helps make header names less ambiguous when you are using multiple libraries. If you have `<LibraryName/header.h>` you are less likely to have to do fiddly tricky stuff to avoid file name conflicts.

Comment: It seems `SDL2` have opted to prefix their filenames with `SDL_` to avoid conflicts. That's just another way of avoiding the same problem.

Comment: I am opposed to putting paths in `include` directives in general because it makes a source file dependent on a particular directory structure, and I've been in situations where I couldn't easily modify either one (and because I'd rather type the path into a makefile once than into source file a dozen times). But I acknowledge that in some circumstances it's not much of a problem.

Comment: @Beta What kind of modifications give you trouble when including paths that are relative to the base of the library?

Comment: @ChristianGibbons: that depends on whether the paths have been changed since the source files were written.

Comment: @Beta That sounds more like a problem of an unstable library (probably one you are modifying and still figuring out how it should be organized).  I would hope a library like SDL2 wouldn't have such issues.

Comment: ***No way I'm typing every conceivable header path into Visual Studio project include paths*** In the past for me including many (50+) folders in the includes greatly increased the compile times. I assume it was because of having to search so many paths for each header.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons: I'll say it again: *in some circumstances it's not much of a problem.*

Comment: @Beta Sorry if I came off as argumentative.  I just wanted to be sure on what the issues were that you came across in case there was a scenario I hadn't considered.  I wanted to confirm that the issue was more with an unstable library, while using something like `SDL2` like OP is shouldn't bring up such scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

Each library **must specify** what directory it expects you to add to the path.  Otherwise, you’re left to trial-and-error to discover the answer that was assumed by whatever *other* libraries you’re using that include headers from the one in question.  Moreover, if you end up needing multiple entries for the same library you increase the chances of collision (and slow down your build).

As for whether a library **should** specify a directory that contains a **subdirectory** named after the library (or more than one such), it’s obviously something of an opinion but I’m willing to say **yes**.  Doing so frees the actual files from needing uglified names to avoid collisions.  This improves the editing experience and allows files *within* the library to refer to one another via unqualified names (when those happen to be unique).

As for SDL itself, the situation is unfortunately confused: some tutorials put a slash in the `#include` and some do not (even on the same site!).  The official FAQ [leaves it out](http://wiki.libsdl.org/FAQDevelopment#Do_I_.23include_.3CSDL.h.3E_or_.3CSDL.2FSDL.h.3E.3F), but seems to be talking about `<>` *vs.* `""`.  The installation instructions say to [**use `sdl2-config`**](http://wiki.libsdl.org/Installation#Linux.2FUnix), which I guess would be the wisest convention to follow.